# Outer table not accessible within nested query in Netezza

Tags: jquery, sql, nested, netezza

In Netezza, I tried to perform the following query.  I get the error:

```
ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  (2) This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting
```

Here is the query.  It can't recognize outer table "A" from the code `A.path` in the line `B.path LIKE (A.path || '%') ESCAPE ''`.

Is there another way to approach this to make the logic work?

I'm guessing since Netezza is a newer DBMS than SQL Server or Oracle, that it just can't handle nested logic like this.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT A.path,
    (
        SELECT
                COUNT(DISTINCT NUM)
            FROM
            B
                    JOIN F ON B.id = F.fed_id
        WHERE   
            B.path LIKE (A.path || '%') ESCAPE ''           
            AND 
            B.code IN ('c', 'C')
    ) as total_count

FROM
    A
    JOIN D ON D.path = A.path and D.code in ('c', 'C')
WHERE
    A.code IN ('c', 'C')
```

## EDIT:

In case the IBM link gets broken, here are the notes from the link.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.0.3/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_correlated_subqueries_ntz_sql.html?lang=en

**Correlated subqueries in Netezza SQL**

*IBM® Netezza® supports both regular and correlated subqueries. Whenever Netezza SQL encounters a regular subquery, it precalculates the subquery once as the example in Subqueries. When the system encounters correlated subqueries in WHERE restrictions, it transforms them internally to equivalent join formats as in the second example in Correlated subqueries.*

*If you choose to use correlated subqueries, keep in mind the following restrictions on the form and placement of correlated subqueries:*

- You can use correlated subqueries in `WHERE` clauses.
  You can use correlated subqueries in `inner join` conditions and with the equal join condition operator.
- You can use correlated subqueries in mixed correlated expressions only in the following form:

  expr(corr_columA, corr_columnB,...) = expr(local_columnX, local_columnY,...)
- You cannot use correlated subqueries in SET operations (`UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT`, and `MINUS`).
- You cannot use correlated subqueries in aggregates with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses.
- You cannot use correlated subqueries in ORed clauses or in `CASE/WHEN` expressions.
- You cannot use correlated subqueries in `IN` lists.
- You cannot use correlated subqueries in `SELECT` lists.

*Note: Because correlated subqueries can drastically affect query performance, consider replacing them with joins for more efficient code whenever possible.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing much about netezza, this rewritten standard-SQL query should do the job:

```
SELECT A.path, COUNT(DISTINCT NUM) AS total_count
FROM   A
JOIN   D ON D.path = A.path
        AND D.code IN ('c', 'C')
LEFT   JOIN B ON B.path LIKE (A.path || '%') ESCAPE ''
             AND B.code IN ('c', 'C')
LEFT   JOIN F ON B.id = F.fed_id
WHERE  A.code IN ('c', 'C')
GROUP  BY A.path;
```

Comment: The counts add up for the ancestors now!!  Thanks!!

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.0.3/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_correlated_subqueries_ntz_sql.html?lang=en

Comment: `You cannot use correlated subqueries in SELECT lists.` That explains it. Quite a list of restrictions ...

Comment: Netezza is meant for data warehouses.  It's very good at bulk inserts, and updates, but lacks functionality in other areas.